# How to iterate from 0 to 10 and i need to change the radio button color for first 0-6 is red and 7-8 yellow and 9-100 green?

Tags: javascript, css, struts2

> I need to keep radio button color for 0-6 is red, 7-8 is yellow and 9-10 is green.. How to resolve it ? I cant able to change the existing bootstrap color..

```
 <s:iterator begin="0" end="10" var="i">
     <li class="rating list-group-item ratingAlign list${i}" style="line-height:8px;">
           <p style="color:red;">${i}</p><br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="initialSetupRating${i}"  name="initialSetup.rating" value="${i}" onclick="changeColor(initialSetupRating${i})"/>
            </li>
    </s:iterator>
```

> It is calling the existing bootstrap so i can't able to change it.. I have attached the bootstrap css in the below.. How to over-ride and keep the color as per my expectation.

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    /* margin: 4px 0 0; */
    margin-top: 1px \9;
    /* line-height: normal; */
}

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the value of the current iteration and set the color based on it? What's the specific issue? I don't see any attempt here to change any colors.

Comment: yes, i tried set. It is working.